# Oracle - how to do this query? IF ELSE IN() clause

Tags: oracle

This is my simplified query

```
SELECT FILTER_IS_LONGS FROM PO_OPEN_FINAL_REPORT 
WHERE FILTER_IS_LONGS in( CASE WHEN testVar = 1 then 'Y' else 'N','Y' END )
```

I get a "missing keyword" error.

The query should basically generate an IN() clause of IN('Y') or IN('N','Y') depending on the value of testVar

I guess it is something to do with escaping `'N','Y'` any help would be appreciated

Comment: shouldn;t this be (CASE testVar WHEN    1 then 'Y' else 'N','Y' END)

Comment: It's not a escaping issue. You cannot use plain SQL to generate dynamic SQL. You have to rethink the whole `WHERE` clause (I see you already have a promising answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally untested, just to give you an idea:

```
SELECT FILTER_IS_LONGS
FROM PO_OPEN_FINAL_REPORT 
WHERE (testVar=1 AND FILTER_IS_LONGS='Y')
OR (testVar<>1 AND FILTER_IS_LONGS IN ('N','Y'))
```

It's probably identical to:

```
SELECT FILTER_IS_LONGS
FROM PO_OPEN_FINAL_REPORT 
WHERE FILTER_IS_LONGS='Y'
OR (testVar<>1 AND FILTER_IS_LONGS='N')
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT FILTER_IS_LONGS FROM PO_OPEN_FINAL_REPORT 
WHERE 
(case 
when testvar=1 and FILTER_IS_LONGS in ('Y') then 1 
when testvar<>1 and FILTER_IS_LONGS in ('Y','N') then 1 
else 0) = 1
```